How to understand the training complexity of Skip-gram model?
Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space explains the design of Skip-gram model, but I have some issues about its training complexity.
According to this paper, the training complexity is proportional to C × (D + D × log2(V)), where

C is the maximum distance of the words.
D is the projected dimension.
V is the size of vocabulary.

But I think its complexity should be D + C × D × log2(V), as given a word, the computing (parameter) of input-projection is fixed to D, no matter what the size of outputs is.
So, how to understand its training complexity correctly?
